# How to avoid circular import looping

Tags: python, game-engine

I am getting confused with importing in python. It seems that I have the problem of circular importing, but I am not sure how to fix this problem in the right way. An example:

file1:

```
value = 5

import file2
file2.set()
```

file2:

```
import file1

def set():
    file1.value = 6
```

Comment: This is a very broad and confused question. As a beginner you really shouldn't be using `exec`. Even as an advanced coder, I wouldn't use it. To avoid circular imports, on the whole you can structure dependencies between modules by taking the common bit of code and putting it into a third module, so the circular modules no longer depend upon each other, but both depend on the third. Keep breaking this until your functionality is properly partitioned.

Comment: I found a technical article that might help you. https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010647

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. put all your code in one file, if it needs to be this tightly linked

```py
value = 5

def set():
    value = 6

set()
```

2. put the code that uses parts from the others in a third file, or in other words break up your code so you avoid the circular references - your example is a bit too simple to make that work though.
3. pass values to functions you want to use, or pass objects you want to modify; importing and modifying another module's globals isn't a very good way to design your program anyway:

```py
# this is my_module.py

def set_value(x):
    x.value = 6


def increment(x):
    return x + 1
```

And elsewhere:

```
import my_module


class X:
    value = 5


x = X()
my_module.set_value(x)

y = 5
y = my_module.increment(y)
```

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning importing in functions, which whilst not relevant here can be very handy when building very generalised libraries